# could not display image from database in one to many relation database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

i was creating a two model for upload a multiple image.for that i have used one to many relationship database for imagelist.but this image's failed to show my browser.here is my code:

model

```
 public class test
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public List<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
    }



//another model



 public class Photo
    {
        public string PhotoId { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
    }
```

here i upload multiple image

Controller

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(test product, IFormFile[] photos)
        {
            test t = new test();
            if (photos == null || photos.Length == 0)
            {
                return Content("File(s) not selected");
            }
            else
            {
                product.Photos = new List<Photo>();
                foreach (IFormFile photo in photos)
                {
                    var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/Images", photo.FileName);
                    var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
                    photo.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    //product.Photos.Add(photo.FileName);
                    product.Photos.Add(new Photo { Image = "Images/" + photo.FileName });
                }
            }
           
           
            _db.test.Add(product);
            _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return View();
        }
```

this controller i used for display:

```
  public IActionResult Index()
        {
           
            return View(_db.test.ToList());
        }
```

here is the view of index.cshtml

```
<h1 class="text-center text-danger">Buy Now!!</h1>
<br /><br />

@using Practise.Models
@model List<test>

<div class="row">

    @foreach (var laptop in Model)
    {
        <div class="col-4 ml-5">
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h4 class="my-4 font-weight-normal">
                        <label style="font-size:23px; color:black;text-align:center">@laptop.Name</label>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <img src="~/@laptop.Photos" alt="Card Image" class="card-img-top" style="height:300px;" />

                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <label style="font-size:20px;color:darkblue"><b>Price:@laptop.Price</b></label>
                        </div>


                        <a asp-action="Details" asp-controller="ShopShow" asp-route-id="@laptop.Id" class="btn btn-primary pull-right btn-outline-light">Details</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    }
</div>
```

when i run the application.i could not find the expection output.that means, could not display image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEgmU.png)

above output,i want to show here photo. what is the solution of this?

Comment: the src object you used in img tag is not a single photo but a collection of photos. You need to put another loop there to make it work like you think or use 0th index to show the first image as default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you need to show the first image only even if multiple images are present. Rewrite your `img` tag like below

```
@if(laptop.Photos!=null && laptop.Photos.Count!=0)
{
   <img src="~/@laptop.Photos[0].Image" alt="Card Image" class="card-img-top" style="height:300px;" />
}
```

Comment: Not working. found error:```NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.```

Comment: Debug and see whether neither the `Model` nor the `Photos` properties are null

Comment: I think some of your product doesn't have Photos. In that case you need to add a null check before rendering the image

Comment: Add another loop for the photos